# Definition of a continuous function (through open sets)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Why the definition of a continuous function defined in terms of inverse function?

$f$ - continuous function, if for every open $V$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.

Comment: I don't know ... why is the sky blue? Could you perhaps post a more specific question? Welcome to MSE, please read other posts to get a feel of this site

Comment: In a topological space, there's no metric to do an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. It's a great exercise to prove that a function in a metric space is $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuous if and only if it's topologically continuous.

Comment: If you think about the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, it is a statement roughly: "given an interval in the range, find an interval in the domain."

Answer (score 1):

It's not defined in terms of an inverse function! If $f : X \to Y$ is not bijective, then an inverse function does not exist! The set $f^{-1}(V)$ is actually defined as
$$ f^{-1}(V) = \{ x \in X : f(x) \in V \}.$$
(And if $f$ *is* bijective, then this is the same as the image of $V$ under the inverse function $f^{-1}$.)

To give you some intuition, consider the example:
$$ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \ \ \ \ \ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \ \  x < 0 \\ 1 & \ \ x \geq 0\end{cases}$$
This function is NOT continuous - it has a jump at $x = 0$. And indeed, if we take $V = (\tfrac 1 2, \infty)$ (which is open), then $f^{-1}(V) = [0, \infty)$ (which is NOT open).

It is possible to show that this definition with open sets is the same as the standard $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, as well as the sequential definition. The advantage of working with the open sets definition is that it generalises to arbitrary topological spaces, whereas the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition only generalises to metric spaces.

Comment: Can we say that $f$ is continuous iff for any open $V$, $f(V)$ is open?

Comment: That's a nice idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work. For example, consider $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ sending $x \mapsto \sin x$. This function is continuous. But if we take $V = \mathbb R$ (which is open), we find that $f(V) = [-1,1]$ (which is NOT open). So the definition fails in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is easier to use than the regular caculus like definition,
f is continuous iff for all x and open V nhood f(x), there be an open U nhood of x with f(U) subset V.

The two defintions can be proven equivalent.
The later for real to real functions can be be shown equivalent to the usual epsilon delta definition.  Likewise, for R^n to R functions.